# Speeding up builds with Xcode and Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am organizing my iOS-Projects with git and Cocoapods. An app is segmented (a lot of Pods for e.g. View, Logic, Themes, etc). So a "bigger" app contains more than 100 Pods and needs really a lot of time to compile/archive/build.

Do you have any ideas/suggestions how to speed things up?
Is there a way to precompile code which is not changed that often?

I already tried:

https://tech.zalando.de/blog/speeding-up-xcode-builds/

Comment: Hey Guys, just wanted to let you know, that I found some sort of solution for my problem. If there are big Pods in my Project that don't change frequently, i compile them to a framework. You can create a pod that contains a framework. just create a pod lib, copy a framework in it and in the podspec use the tag vendored_frameworks. I do this even with bigger extern libraries such as SwiftyJSON, EUREKA! and so on, compile time is reduced from minutes to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems and developed my own utility  [**Rugby**](https://github.com/swiftyfinch/Rugby).

You can use it like that:

```sh
pod install && rugby
```

And all your pods will be moved to cache. It's an easy enough and fast solution.
Feel free to contact me if you have any issues.